# How to check if object value in array already exists using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to check if an object value already in an array exists ?
If not push a value

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h9zctLqz/

html:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="input" name="input">
  <button type="button" name="save">save</button>
</form>
```

jquery:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $myData = [];

    $('button[name=save]').on('click', function(){
        var input = $('#input').val();
            $myData.indexOf({'input':input}) === -1 ? $myData.push({'input':input}) : console.log('already exists');
      console.log($myData);
  });   
});
```

Comment: no, just for testing. The whole thing should look like {product:XXXXX, quantity: XXXX}, if the product is already in array just update the quantity if not save the whole object into the array

Comment: this info actually changes the question completely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first thing you should know is that, in javascript:

```
({ 'input': input} === { 'input': input }) // returns false
```

`===` compares the object reference, not the way the objects look.

That means that `indexOf({input: input})` will *never* return anything else than -1.

You can solve this by using `some`. `some` takes a function to compare stuff, so you can write your own "equals" (instead of `indexOf` using `===`).

```
if ($myData.some(item => item.input === input)) console.log("exists")
else $myData.push({input: input});
```

Comment: Welcome to the *privileged users* ! ;)

Comment: @Jonasw Well spotted! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
if(myArray.find(x => x.input === input)){
console.log("Exist");
} else{
anotherarray.push({'input':input});
}
```

> The
>   [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
>   method returns a value in the array, if an element in the array
>   satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is
>   returned.
>
> If you want to get array of matching elements, use
>   [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
>   method instead:

```
myArray.filter(x => x.id === input)
```

> If you want to get array of `another property` properties, you can do
>   this with
>   [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
>   method:

```
myArray.filter(x => x.id === input).map(x => x.anotherproperty)
```

Comment: Not sure why this is upvoted; it doesn't work. Aside from the `:''` syntax error, `filter()` always returns an array - even an empty one. Using an array in a condition will always equate to `true`, hence the `else` is never hit.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use the *includes* array method *array.includes(some value)* and then if it does not include as includes returns a bool you can push. Note this is plain Javascript.
[Array includes method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(array)
if (array.includes(2)) {
  array.push(20);
}
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

These objects will have two different references so it will always return false.
Use .some or .find and do a value comparison of the .input field.

```
const itemExists = $myData.some(el => el.input === input);
if(itemExists) {
   console.log("Already exsists");
} 
else {
   $myData.push({'input':input})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a perfect usecase for a hash table:

```
var hash={},result=[];

$('button[name=save]').on('click', function(){
    var input = $('#input').val();
    if(hash[input]){
      hash[input].quantity++;
    }else{
      result.push(hash[input]={input,quantity:1});
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

indexOf works well with Strings but to check within an array you cannot simply use it.

Other method could be iterating whole array and check but that would be very costly in terms of time complexity.

So best answer would be to use simple map in such cases. Try below -

```
$('document').ready(function(){ 
var myData = new Object(); // or var map = {};

$('button[name=save]').on('click', function(){
    var input = $('#input').val(); 
        if(myData[input] != input) 
            myData[input] = input;
        else
          console.log('already exists'); 


});   
});
```